# Program closing down when clicking on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a beginner trying to code a Tic Tac Toe program (using Python in VSC) with this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yniQ15A7MLk. But when I try to make the circle show up when clicked, the program closes down when I click on the screen and the terminal prints this error message:

```
TypeError: function missing required argument 'radius' (pos 4)
```

I don't think it's the clicking function, since I get the results printed in text in the VSC terminal. But it doesn't show up in the program window. And I don't think it's something in the draw function, since I tried with an image instead and the same thing happened (program closing down when I clicked on the screen).

```
import pygame
import numpy

pygame.init()


white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

height = 700
width = 700
line_thickness = 20

display = pygame.display.set_mode((height, width))
display.fill(black)

board = numpy.zeros((3, 3))

def lines():
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (50, 250), (650, 250), line_thickness)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (50, 450), (650, 450), line_thickness)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (250, 50), (250, 650), line_thickness)
    pygame.draw.line(display, white, (450, 50), (450, 650), line_thickness)

lines()

square_size = 200
o_radius = 60
o_width = 15

def draw_figures():
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if board[row, col] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(display, red, ((int(row * square_size + square_size // 2), int(col * square_size + square_size // 2)), o_radius, o_width))

def marked_square(row, col, player):
    board[row, col] = player

def available_square(row, col):
    return board[row, col] == 0

player = 1


pygame.display.update()


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x = event.pos[0]
            mouse_y = event.pos[1]

            clicked_row = int(mouse_y // 200)
            clicked_col = int(mouse_x // 200)

            if available_square(clicked_row, clicked_col):
                if player == 1:
                    marked_square(clicked_row, clicked_row, 1)
                    player = 2

                elif player == 2:
                    marked_square(clicked_row, clicked_row, 2)
                    player = 1

                draw_figures()

                print(board)
```

Comment: pygame.draw.circle only has 3 parameters, your brackets are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

in:

```
pygame.draw.circle(display, red, ((int(row * square_size + square_size // 2), int(col * square_size + square_size // 2)), o_radius, o_width))
```

Your brackets are incorrect, so you only have 3 parameters

```
pygame.draw.circle(
    display, 
    red, 
    ((int(row * square_size + square_size // 2), int(col * square_size + square_size // 2)), o_radius, o_width)
    )
```

I assume you mean

```
pygame.draw.circle(display, red, (int(row * square_size + square_size // 2), int(col * square_size + square_size // 2)), o_radius, o_width)
```

It would probably be cleaner to have some helper variables

```
x = int(row * square_size + square_size // 2)
y = int(col * square_size + square_size // 2)
pygame.draw.circle(display, red, (x, y), o_radius, o_width)
```